# Metro has encountered an error: While trying to resolve module 'firebase'

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, node-modules

I took this error after I started the emulator, I add my codes under the image and error on the terminal. This is my App.js file
[Error Image on Emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pffip.png)

> error: Error: While trying to resolve module `firebase` from file `/Users/capcapbakkal/Desktop/RNKurs/identifyVerification/index.js`, the package `/Users/capcapbakkal/Desktop/RNKurs/identifyVerification/node_modules/firebase/package.json` was successfully found. However, this package itself specifies a `main` module field that could not be resolved (`/Users/capcapbakkal/Desktop/RNKurs/identifyVerification/node_modules/firebase/index`. Indeed, none of these files exist:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import 'firebase/compat/auth';
import 'firebase/compat/firestore';
```

and

```
componentDidMount() {
    const firebaseApp = initializeApp({
      apiKey: "AIzaSyCpM2dwcUvJqVaKz856hz",
      authDomain: "authentication-b4",
      projectId: "authen",
      storageBucket: "authenticat",
      messagingSenderId: "7532",
      appId: "1:753222",
      measurementId: "G-"
    });// I changed this, it isn't wrong

  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I encountered the same issue with my React Native app build with expo

```json
//package.json

"expo": "^44.0.0",
"firebase": "^9.8.1",
```

```sh
Metro has encountered an error: While trying to resolve module `idb` from file `/Users/cerebra/workspace/retailshake/recognizeReborn/node_modules/@firebase/app/dist/esm/index.esm2017.js`, the package `/Users/cerebra/workspace/retailshake/recognizeReborn/node_modules/idb/package.json` was successfully found. However, this package itself specifies a `main` module field that could not be resolved (`/Users/cerebra/workspace/retailshake/recognizeReborn/node_modules/idb/build/index.cjs`. Indeed, none of these files exist:
```

fixed with [**downgrading firebase**](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/releases/tag/firebase%409.7.0)

```json
//package.json

"firebase": "9.7.0",
```

Comment: This did it for me too!

Answer (score 3):

I had this same issue, I downgraded the Firebase version from 9.6.8 to 8.2.3 and it worked for me.

Here is a reference that could be helpful.

https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/issues/3066

Comment: worked for me too.