# Metro has encountered an error: While trying to resolve module `clsx`... ...specifies a `main` module field that could not be resolved

Tags: reactjs, node.js, material-ui, expo, package.json

I am trying to use react expo with material ui to create a gym log app but cannot get past this error when I try to use anything in material ui. I am running windows 11, node.js 18.18.1, and am using "npx create-expo-app --template" on the navigation preset. I notice that the app comes with 7 vulnerabilities straight out of its creation, but they appear to be unrelated to this issue. I add in some components from material ui to index.js, and install their dependencies as installation instructions say on the documentation.

```
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

import EditScreenInfo from '../../components/EditScreenInfo';
import { Text, View } from '../../components/Themed';
import { DataGrid, GridRowsProp, GridColDef  } from '@mui/x-data-grid';


const rows: GridRowsProp = [
  { id: 1, col1: 'Hello', col2: 'World' },
  { id: 2, col1: 'DataGridPro', col2: 'is Awesome' },
  { id: 3, col1: 'MUI', col2: 'is Amazing' },
];

const columns: GridColDef[] = [
  { field: 'col1', headerName: 'Column 1', width: 150 },
  { field: 'col2', headerName: 'Column 2', width: 150 },
];

export default function TabOneScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.title}>Tab One</Text>
      <View style={styles.separator} lightColor="#eee" darkColor="rgba(255,255,255,0.1)" />
      <EditScreenInfo path="app/(tabs)/index.tsx" />
      <DataGrid rows={rows} columns={columns}/>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
  separator: {
    marginVertical: 30,
    height: 1,
    width: '80%',
  },
});
```

After I run npm run web, it gives me this in the terminal:

```
Web Bundling failed 4606ms
Unable to resolve "clsx" from "node_modules\@mui\x-data-grid\components\columnHeaders\GridBaseColumnHeaders.js"
Web node_modules\expo-router\node/render.js ▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓░░░░░░░ 58.3% (726/951)
Metro error: Metro has encountered an error: While trying to resolve module `clsx` from file `D:\Code\gym-log\webapp\gym-log\node_modules\@mui\x-data-grid\components\columnHeaders\GridBaseColumnHeaders.js`, the package `D:\Code\gym-log\webapp\gym-log\node_modules\clsx\package.json` was successfully found. However, this package itself specifies a `main` module field that could not be resolved (`D:\Code\gym-log\webapp\gym-log\node_modules\clsx\dist\clsx.mjs`. Indeed, none of these files exist:

  * D:\Code\gym-log\webapp\gym-log\node_modules\clsx\dist\clsx.mjs(.web.ts|.ts|.web.tsx|.tsx|.web.js|.js|.web.jsx|.jsx|.web.json|.json|.web.cjs|.cjs|.web.scss|.scss|.web.sass|.sass|.web.css|.css)
  * D:\Code\gym-log\webapp\gym-log\node_modules\clsx\dist\clsx.mjs\index(.web.ts|.ts|.web.tsx|.tsx|.web.js|.js|.web.jsx|.jsx|.web.json|.json|.web.cjs|.cjs|.web.scss|.scss|.web.sass|.sass|.web.css|.css): D:\Code\gym-log\webapp\gym-log\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph.js (289:17)
```

I checked for clsx.mjs, and it exists. Under clsx's package.json I see this:

```
  "name": "clsx",
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "repository": "lukeed/clsx",
  "description": "A tiny (234B) utility for constructing className strings conditionally.",
  "module": "dist/clsx.mjs",
  "unpkg": "dist/clsx.min.js",
  "main": "dist/clsx.js",...
```

All those files exist, so I'm not really sure what's wrong here. I checked looking for similar issues, but none with solutions that worked for this particular case. So far, I have tried npm install, npm update, npm audit fix and with --force, deleting package-lock.json and node_modules and running npm install, using node.js 20.8.1, and changing metroconfig.js. I don't see how I can change the version of material-ui or react here. Some of the solutions I tried are below:

[Metro has encountered an error: While trying to resolve module 'firebase'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70398442/metro-has-encountered-an-error-while-trying-to-resolve-module-firebase)
https://github.com/react-native-camera/react-native-camera/issues/2626
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wbkEhfWotm8

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, MUI component libraries (including Material UI and MUI X) are not compatible with React Native. They're designed for the web platform only.